# What's the relation between the parallax distance and the luminosity distance?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astronomy, space-expansion, parallax

i have read that Riess and his team are able to measure $H_0$ from supernovae calibrated using Cepheid in a model independent way.

from what i have gathered they find the absolute luminosity of Cepheid $M_c$  with the parallax method and a bunch of other geometric methods then,  once they have $ M_c$, they use the luminosity redshift relation of SN Ia to find $M_{sn}$.

my question is:

once they have the parallax distance of Cepheid, how do they find  their distance moduli   without imposing a model? in other words, how do they convert the parallax distance in the luminosity distance without assuming a model? otherwise i don't understand how can they find their absolute luminosity or the distance moduli needed to find $M_c$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it belongs to [Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Farcher can you move it there or i need to rewrite it?

Comment: I do not know how to migrate a question so just cut and paste you question into Astronomy SE adding a note at the start.